# dynamically generate a model based on a SQL Table in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a model that can be dynamically built on the fly, based on a SQL Table. I will not know the SQL table beforehand, so the model needs to be dynamic. There are too many possible-tables for it to be feasible to pre-build a model for each one. I would like a user to be able to go through, select a table from a list, and then a model be generated based on that table. Any insight or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: A model is usually strong typed and therefor known at build-time. Who are your users? Developers or application users?

Comment: You do realize that adding a (Model) class would require the application to be rebuilt?
Have you thought about Entity Framework DB First development?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, so here's an equally broad suggestion (not answer): many CMS (for example Sitefinity) allow for the creation of custom content types for the web. It'll then create some sort of schema document that will be persisted and loaded each time the application starts, to be able to reference the table(s). They use Open Access as the ORM. I'm not sure if this functionality is a feature of Open Access, or if they just build on top of it. Other CMSes must do similar things (on the fly content types). All such created models will have to inherit from the same type for CRUD

Answer (score 0):

There are several, slightly different approaches I can think of. All would consider a codegenerator (eg. T4 Text template Tool)

One approach we used was to Map all Columnsdefinition and Tabledefinition in separate own Tables in the Database. That is not compellingly necessary since you could use the Information_Schema of the Database to retrieve the Informations you need for a simple model. But! As soon you need additional information   (this is more likely the case) for the columns and tables I would consider to map them as own Datarecords in own Tables.

Concrete I mean by column and table definition is ment the information needed to create the models.
E.g. Table DialogColumn had columns like Columnname (nVarchar), displayname (nVarchar), recordhistory (bit), UID_Dialogtable and some other "meta"-data that represented a property of the model. A Table, lets name it also Dialogtable provied then all properties, eg. tablename, displayname, onsavingscript etc.

With this information you could generate typewrappers as models.
preferabely you would create them as a prestep in the build process of the compiler or just once (depending on your archithecture).
For extending and altering a model structure you could write a separate tool thats manages the table and columns entry in the database for you and compiles the assembly you need.

and so on and so forth